# Can JQuery read and write to an access DataBase

Tags: jquery, html, ms-access-2010

I was wondering if i can use  Jquery to connect to a Microsoft Access database? I have been doing some research and have been  unable able to locate anything.  The database would not be towards a production site, but rather for a small group of users.

Thank you

Comment: Or with http://nodejs.org/

Answer (score 1):

I call JavaScript "a language without teeth", it can't access a database, It can just access an API to the database. and the same for jQuery since it is a javascript lib.

Comment: Well, that's only true in a Browser context. Accessing some device's camera (for example) is one hell of a teeth and is possible using projects like Apache Cordova. Being more picky, I can tell you that Javascript can interact with databases like **IndexedDB** or **WebSQL** in Browser environment as well.

Comment: Yes, these are the denture in this case :)

Comment: Is there s direct way to connect to an access Database, without an API? Or do we need a dedicated database to be able to complete the connection? We do not have access to server to be able to access SQL Server.

Comment: You need the database to expose an API with a URL and Javascript will be able to access 'Not sure if this is possible through access', Or have a programming language in the middle which implement the access to the db and expose the API url to the javascript to use.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly no, but via AJAX it could communicate with a server-side script that could.